# jQuery and piroBox don't like <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, doctype

I'm trying to use the piroBox [(http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/index.php](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/index.php)) jQuery plug-in to make a gallery. I'm also using `<!DOCTYPE html>`. With this `DOCTYPE`, the images that are supposed to appear in a modal dialog appear at the bottom of the page. Removing the `DOCTYPE` makes it perform as expected.

Is there any way to make the plug-in and the doctype play nice without changing the `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: As @nighthwk1 asks: what browser(s) is (are) this presenting a problem in?

Comment: Chrome and the IE9 beta. Chrome in particular is a tier 1 browser for the project.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? I tested `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` with the examples from piroBox, and it worked in Safari. If you're using IE, you might need to install an HTML5 compatibility script: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/

Comment: Chrome and the IE9 beta. Chrome in particular is a tier 1 browser for the project.